# Simple way to apply distinct transformations to different parts of one vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a single vector
$\begin{pmatrix} a \\b \\ c \\ d \end{pmatrix} $, where I want to transform different elements using different matrices $X$ and $Y$. For example, I want to be able to evaluate the following expression:

$X\begin{pmatrix} a \\0 \\ 0 \\ d \end{pmatrix} +Y \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\b \\ c \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $

Is there a simpler way to do this, perhaps with one well-designed matrix?

Comment: Consider elemination matrices. E.g. $E = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ so that $E\begin{pmatrix} a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ d\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1,...,X_4$ be column vectors of $X$ in order and $Y_1,...,Y_4$ be column vectors of Y in order too. For standard basis vectors $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$

$v=c_1e_1+c_2e_2+c_3e_3+c_4e_4 \Rightarrow T(v)=c_1T(e_1)+c_2T(e_2)+c_3T(e_3)+c_4T(e_4)=A\begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \\ c_4 \end{pmatrix}=Av$

$T(e_1)=X_1$

$T(e_2)=Y_2$

$T(e_3)=Y_3$

$T(e_4)=X_4$

so $A $ is a matrix whose i th column is $T(e_i)$